# How to set or test this.$parent in Vuejs unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2

In my component set

```
data(){
categories: this.$parent.categories => which I set in main.js
}
```

Code file main.js

```
import categories from '../config/categories';
new Vue({
    router,
    data: {
        categories: categories
}
});
```

I created 1 function unit test

```
it(‘check component is a button’,() => {
const wrapper = shallow(FormSearch);
expect(wrapper.contains(‘button’)).toBe(true);
});
```

I run test then show error: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property ‘categories’ of undefined"
How to fix it. Help me.

Comment: If you component depends on a parent, you also need to embed that parent in the unit tests themselves

Answer (score 0):

Why not import you categories config file directly into your component?

`import Categories from '../config/categories'`

then your data method can directly access it:

`data () { return { categories: Categories }}`

You'll find that much easier to test

Comment: yes, thanks you. I changed. But it happens error other
 Cannot find module '../../config/categories' from 'mycomponet.vue'.
Although. I run project on browser just working well.
How to fix it. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

yes, thanks you. I changed. I run test then it happens error other

```
Cannot find module '../../config/categories' from 'mycomponet.vue'.
```

Although. I run project on browser just working well.
How to fix it. Thanks you very much

Comment: You are using 'shallow' in your test. This only loads the component but without its dependencies. Use mount instead

Answer (score 0):

For Testing , you can set mock data to escape `undefined` error while testing . But it is not standard solution .....

```
it(‘check component is a button’,() => {
   const wrapper = shallow(FormSearch);
   let mockCategories = { // mock category data }
   wrapper.$parent = {
     categories: mockCategories
   }
   expect(wrapper.contains(‘button’)).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
const Parent = {
  data: () => ({
    val: true
  }),
  template: '<div />'
}

const wrapper = shallowMount(TestComponent, {
  parent: Parent
})
```